# Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to read a response XML from a service to a class to use it.
if i use this URL `https://btsvcs.college.edu/HR/Employee/ID/NAGWA_N@COLLEGE.EDU`

The response XML will be like this:

```
<Data>
  <Record id="PA01051" rowOrder="0">
    <employee_id>20000343</employee_id>
  </Record>
</Data>
```

I had create my class to be the same with the response XML.

This is the class:

```
public class GetEmployeeIdByEmail
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class Record
    {

        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public string employee_id { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public Record Record { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After that i had make a function to read the XML using  the `HttpClient`

This is the function:

```
public async Task<GetEmployeeIdByEmail> GetEmployeeIdByEmail()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var url = "https://btsvcs.college.edu/HR/Employee/ID/NAGWA_N@COLLEGE.EDU";
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
    GetEmployeeIdByEmail responseData = null;

    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        responseData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<GetEmployeeIdByEmail>();
    }

    return responseData;
}
```

If I make a break point on this function and tracking it step by step always get back to website to read the xml after this line

`var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);` and no response back to complete the debugging.

I don't know what is reason for that.

Comment: Does the application throw an error? does it hang? what do you mean by `no response back`? Clarify.

Comment: Check your url. Your code works fine. Test with "https://duckduckgo.com" Could be name resolution for  "btsvcs.college.edu".

Comment: @Nkos their is no exception the application still reload.

Comment: @ivw the url is correct and the response is so fast

Comment: What status code are you getting back? 200? 400? 500?

Comment: Could be a certificate issue.

Comment: @Sven Lion their is no response but must be 200

Comment: "must be 200", don't "must be" it. Assert it. Is it actually 200 or not?

Comment: that `no response` is where you are loosing me.

Comment: @SvenLion yes 200

Comment: @Nkosi that what make me nervous

Comment: HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
            try
            {
                responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

Comment: @Hansy is this a console app? looks like you are experiencing a deadlock. You need to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: mvc project with c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ivw answer to use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024856/dns-resolution-failure-in-httpclient-throws-unhandled-aggregateexception)

That's helps me to use the code written in the question.

```
responseMessage = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

Instead of

```
responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

and remove the async from the function header

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
try
{
    responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Also the browser still loading

Comment: take a look here change exception settings may help get more details on the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024856/dns-resolution-failure-in-httpclient-throws-unhandled-aggregateexception

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is that `client.GetAsync` is asynchronous method that makes `async I/O` to network to perform the request and receive a response. When such async operation occurs and there is an `await` keyword in the before the method call the control return up to by the stack to the caller of the method. And the when client gets a response method resumes from where it left.

Try set your break point at a next line after `await` and and will be hit once request is performed.

Comment: It's not going to the next point, but After make it .Result; and remove the await it's working correctly

Comment: @Hansy, because you made it synchronous. Have you tried to put a breakpoint on a next line?